# NPN BJT Operation - What does it mean for the Collector - Base junction to be reversed biased?

Tags: bjt, npn, biasing

According to this screen grab the Collector Base junction must be "reversed biased". I seem to be confused about the meaning of that. I thought that the Collector needed to be at a higher voltage than the base, therefor the collector base junction is forward biased (the first node mentioned is at a higher voltage than the second node mentioned). Or would you actually call that being reversed biased since its a pn junction (a diode) that is reversed biased (anode is more negative than the cathode)?

[image]

Comment: It's reverse-biased because of the *actual* base-collector PN junction being reverse-biased, as you wrote last.

Comment: The base is p-type (= anode), the collector is n-type (= cathode). The cathode is more positive than the anode, therefore reverse biased.

Comment: You can't infer it's reverse biased from that screen grab alone : you also need to know the relative values of Vcc and Vbb which aren't stated.

Comment: @jonk thank you for clearing that up for me

Comment: The base-collector junction doesn't "have to be reverse biased". When the transistor is operating in the saturation region it is forward biased. It is commonly reverse biased when the transistor is operating as a more-or-less linear amplifier, rather than as a switch.

Answer (score 1):

An NPN transistor can be modeled like two diodes sharing a cathode as the base. That means the base-collector would look like a diode pointing up in your image (reverse biased) because it is pointing opposite of normal current flow.  Applying a voltage to the base more positive than the emitter (0.6v or greater) will cause current to flow through the base and decrease the base's effectiveness as a cathode. That is, it looks less like a diode which prevents current flow from collector to base (and on to emitter).

I am speaking of current flow in the above paragraph which is traditional. In reality, a positive voltage applied to the base allows electrons to flow from emitter through nose, and that reduces the effectiveness of the base as a cathode which allows additional electrons to flow up through the collector.

Answer (score 0):

> the Collector Base junction must be "reversed biased"

It doesn't "have to be" in general. The B-C junction is forward biased when the transistor is saturated, and reverse biased when the transistor is in the linear region, i.e. not saturated.

> I thought that the Collector needed to be at a higher voltage than the base

In linear operating mode - yes. In saturation - no. Here's an example of a saturated NPN switch. Since the switch is on the more negative side of the load, it's also called a *low side* switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTWlPE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>